# Check if a number is prime or not in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am wondering what's the best way to check whether a number is prime or not using sql. I was able to generate the sequence of numbers from 1 to 1000 but I would like to identify which number is a prime. Can somebody share your thoughts on this.Thanks.

```
SELECT i 
  FROM
(
select
     i0.i
    +i1.i*2
    +i2.i*4
    +i3.i*8
    +i4.i*16
    +i5.i*32
    +i6.i*64
    +i7.i*128
    +i8.i*256
    +i9.i*512
    as i
from
               (select 0 as i union select 1) as i0
    cross join (select 0 as i union select 1) as i1
    cross join (select 0 as i union select 1) as i2
    cross join (select 0 as i union select 1) as i3
    cross join (select 0 as i union select 1) as i4
    cross join (select 0 as i union select 1) as i5
    cross join (select 0 as i union select 1) as i6
    cross join (select 0 as i union select 1) as i7
    cross join (select 0 as i union select 1) as i8
    cross join (select 0 as i union select 1) as i9
) Z
WHERE i>=1 AND i<=1000;
```

Comment: do you only have to check primes between 1 and 1000?

Comment: Yes, even if it's greater than 1000 thats fine... But I just want to display the prime numbers at the end...

Comment: Make a table of prime numbers then test if your number is present in that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `self join` to check for primes from the table of generated numbers. Primes have 2 factors, a conditional check would be sufficient.

```
select val
from (select x.val,x1.val as divisor,mod(x.val,x1.val) as remaindr
      from x
      join x x1 on x1.val <= x.val
     ) t
group by val
having sum(case when remaindr = 0 then 1 else 0 end) = 2
```

[`Sample Demo`](http://rextester.com/IQTWT69557)

An optimization for the above is to check for divisors in the range of 1 to sqrt(number). In that case the only factor for a prime number would be 1, and the conditional check can be changed accordingly.

```
select val
from (select x.val,x1.val as divisor,mod(x.val,x1.val) as remaindr
      from x
      join x x1 on x.val >= pow(x1.val,2)
      where x.val > 1 --excluding 1 as it is neither prime nor composite
     ) t
group by val
having sum(case when remaindr = 0 then 1 else 0 end) = 1
```

Comment: if you have a generated numbers table, this should work with mysql too.

Comment: It worked fine... But what's the thinking behind this logic  sum(case when remaindr = 0 then 1 else 0 end) = 2 ?

Comment: it is to check for the number of factors of a given number. *primes* have only 1 and the number itself as factors ( 2 in total).

Answer (score 1):

This is *not* a good fit for SQL.  But you can do it as:

```
select n.*
from n
where not exists (select 1
                  from n n2
                  where n2.n <= sqrt(n.n) and n2.n > 1 and
                        n.n mod n2.n = 0
                 ) and
      n > 1;  -- 1 is deemed to not be prime
```

You may need to wait a little while to start seeing numbers.

I should note that in MySQL, a shorter way to generate the numbers is:

```
select (@rn := @rn + 1) as i
from (select 0 as i union select 1) as i0 cross join
     (select 0 as i union select 1) as i1 cross join
     (select 0 as i union select 1) as i2 cross join
     (select 0 as i union select 1) as i3 cross join
     (select 0 as i union select 1) as i4 cross join
     (select 0 as i union select 1) as i5 cross join
     (select 0 as i union select 1) as i6 cross join
     (select 0 as i union select 1) as i7 cross join
     (select 0 as i union select 1) as i8 cross join
     (select 0 as i union select 1) as i9 cross join
     (select @rn := 0) params
having i >= 1 and i <= 1000;
```

This should be faster because no intermediate table is materialized.  In addition, adding 1 is probably slightly faster than the arithmetic, although the difference is calculation may be rather small.